# GPO Login script opens intranet page, but will not allow hyperlinks to open new tabs\windows when Chrome is default browser

Tags: google-chrome, login-script, gpo

We have a login script, deployed via GPO, that does a multitude of operations for us including mapping network drives and opening our intranet page. Currently if a user has Google Chrome set as their default browser, the intranet page will open at login as normal but will not allow any external hyperlinks (from emails, saved links, etc..) to open a new tab or window within chrome until the original window that opened chrome from the GPO is closed and then it will operate as normal. Below is the snippet of the code that opens the intranet page:

```
Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("http://ourintranetpage")
```

I've created a user and machine to test the issue and I denied the user from receiving the login script from the GPO and instead created a scheduled task to run the script on login of test user. The reasoning was to try and comment out other portions of the login script to see if there was any conflict during the running of the script. But when the script is run as a schedule task chrome will act as normal and open new tabs\windows. 
When IE or Firefox is selected as default browser, the problem does not exist. We cannot force a default browser as many execs have a different preference of browser.

I'm sorry if this post lacks information needed for assistance, please let me know if I need to provide more information, this is my first post. :)

Answer (score 0):

Found this to be a solution:

```
Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WSHShell.Run "ourintranetsite", 1, false
```